# Can not deploy web-starter nodejs app on Heroku

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, heroku

I am new to front-end and was trying to fork and follow the steps to deploy the work on Heroku, but it failed. My changes are available [here](https://github.com/hhimanshu/web-starter-kit/commit/5a074e4520eda5ca230e9431d7b420600471ae1a).

The steps I performed as following

- Forked the repo
- Created a new branch to deploy changes.
- Made changes([ref](https://github.com/hhimanshu/web-starter-kit/commit/5a074e4520eda5ca230e9431d7b420600471ae1a)) as described in [deploy](https://github.com/hhimanshu/web-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/deploy.md) page for [Heroku](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/docs/recipes/node-heroku.md)
- ran `heroku local web`
- Hit http://localhost:5000 as per Heroku's [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#build-your-app-and-run-it-locally)
  [image]I see error on web page saying Cannot GET / (snapshot attached)

My repository is available on GitHub at https://github.com/hhimanshu/web-starter-kit/

What am I doing wrong? Kindly help

Comment: You pushed your "dist" folder, right? (to Heroku, I mean)

Comment: @hisener, everything is local at the moment

Comment: I posted an answer, please take a look. Take care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I tested on my local computer. It works fine. I do not see any difference but I'll write the steps I followed. Maybe you will see the difference.

- forked the repo
- `git clone` the repo
- created a new branch
- `mkdir dist`
- created and copy-pasted `dist/package.json` and `dist/server.js` from [there](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/docs/recipes/node-heroku.md).
- changed the directory `dist` to `dist/public` in gulpfile.babel.js
- runned `gulp` in root folder
- `npm install` in root folder
- `npm install` in dist folder
- first tested with `npm start`. it's ok on `localhost:3000`
- `heroku local web` in `dist` folder

And result ([github repo](https://github.com/hisener/web-starter-kit/tree/heroku)):

```
[WARN] No ENV file found
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
6:03:42 PM web.1 |  > @ start /home/hisener/Projects/web-starter-kit-heroku/dist
6:03:43 PM web.1 |  > node server.js
6:03:43 PM web.1 |  Server running...
```

[image: web-starter-kit-heroku-local]

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I checked out your `heroku` branch and ran `npm install` in `project root` and `dist` folder. When I run `npm start`, it gives me same `Cannot GET /`, did I miss anything? or did you miss to checkin some file?

Comment: @daydreamer You should also run ``gulp`` before ``npm start``.

Comment: The latest place where I am stuck now is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039009/can-not-deploy-gulp-application-on-heroku-heroku-local-web-works-though. You may know about this

Comment: I've added an answer to your new question. Please do not hesitate upvote and accept the answers. :)